# Python pandas: apply on separated values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I sum values in dataframe that a separated by semicolon?

Got:

```
                  col1            col2
2018-03-05         2.1               8
2018-03-06           8           3.1;2
2018-03-07         1;1             8;1
```

Need:

```
                  col1            col2
2018-03-05         2.1               8
2018-03-06           8             5.1
2018-03-07           2               9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for processes each column with [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html), cast to `float` and `sum` per columns:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(';', expand=True).astype(float).sum(axis=1))
```

Or process each value separately by [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: sum(map(float, x.split(';'))))
print (df)
            col1  col2
2018-03-05   2.1   8.0
2018-03-06   8.0   5.1
2018-03-07   2.0   9.0
```

EDIT:

If numeric with strings columns is possible use [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) for exclude numeric and working only with `string`s columns with `;`:

```
print (df)
           col1   col2  col3
2018-03-05  2.1      8     1
2018-03-06    8  3.1;2     2
2018-03-07  1;1    8;1     8

cols = df.select_dtypes(exclude=np.number).columns
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.split(';', expand=True).astype(float).sum(axis=1))
print (df)
            col1  col2  col3
2018-03-05   2.1   8.0     1
2018-03-06   8.0   5.1     2
2018-03-07   2.0   9.0     8
```

Comment: Thanks! But for the first solution i recieve `Nan` for all values without semicolon. For the second one `AttributeError: ("'int' object has no attribute 'split'"...`

Comment: @VadimK - Simpliest is `df = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.split(';', expand=True).astype(float).sum(axis=1))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.vectorize` if performance is an issue:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(np.vectorize(lambda x: sum(map(float, x.split(';'))))(df.values),
                   columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
```

**Performance benchmarking**

```
def jpp(df):
    res = pd.DataFrame(np.vectorize(lambda x: sum(map(float, x.split(';'))))(df.values),
                       columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
    return res

def jez(df):
    return df.applymap(lambda x: sum(map(float, x.split(';'))))

df = pd.concat([df]*1000)

%timeit jpp(df)  # 11 ms per loop
%timeit jez(df)  # 21.3 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df['col2'] = df.col2.map(lambda s: sum(float(e) for e in s.split(';')))
```

Comment: Your solution will not sum values of `col1`